# pandas to_json takes lot of time for large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I want all the columns to be converted into json records except for one column source. So output column should have 2 columns, `source and json_content` I am using below code but it takes much time for large data set. How can I write the same logic in more efficient way?

```
df = df[['source']].assign(
            json_content=df.drop('source', axis=1).to_json(
                orient='records', lines=True,
                default_handler=CustomJSONEncoder).splitlines())
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `df[[col]].assign(json_content=df.drop(...))` instead of `df['json_content'] = df.drop(...)`? Is the `df.drop().to_json()` on its own slow?